# Find the precentage of products ordered

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, percentage, product

Of all the products available in the “books” category, what percentage were ordered in the last 3 months?

```
ORDERS
order_id
customer_id
order_date
product_id

PRODUCTS
product_id
product_name
product_category
product_price
```

Answer (score 0):

I assuming you are after a counter percentage. If you want to compare values you will need to change the select below a bit. 
Below is how I would do it. Please note that I have't run it so you may have some syntax errors but it should be easy to fix them.

```
WITH books AS (
  SELECT order_date
    FROM orders
    JOIN products
      ON orders.product_id = products.product_id
   WHERE products.product_category = 'books'
),
last_three_months AS (
  SELECT 0 as counter_1, count(*) AS counter_2
    FROM books
   WHERE order_date > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE());
),
total_orders AS (
  select count(*) AS counter_1, 0 as counter_2
  FROM books
),
all_together AS (
 SELECT counter_1, counter_2
   FROM last_three_months
 UNION ALL
 SELECT counter_1, counter_2
   FROM total_orders
),
sale_sums AS (
  SELECT SUM(counter_2) AS counter_2, SUM(counter_1) AS counter_1
    FROM all_together
)
SELECT counter_2/counter_1 * 100
FROM sale_sums
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple query. This is a simple PSQL. Learn simple syntaxes and you will be able to do it by yourself.

```
WITH ordersLastThree as
(
 Select o.* FROM PRODUCTS p,ORDERS o where p.product_id=o.product_id and
 p.product_category = [Books product_category] 
 and o.order_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) 
)
 Select (ISNULL((Select count(*) from ordersLastThree),1)*100) / count(o.*) as Result
 FROM PRODUCTS p,ORDERS o where p.product_id=o.product_id and
 p.product_category = [Books product_category]
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have to tell us the data base you are using then..

it will varry accordingly..
if it Mysql and C# fornt end then the code wiil

....accept the returned row by sql query into daatareader then apply calculation. i hope it clear your doubt